# Is it possible to improve the weight of perfect bipartite matchings faster than with Bellman-Ford?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, perfect-matchings

If $G\left(A\cup B,\ E=\lbrace\lbrace a, b\rbrace\,|\, a\in A,\, b\in B\rbrace\right)$ is a weighted bipartite graph and $M_0$ an initial perfect matching, then the optimality of $M_0$ can be verified by the absence of negative cycles in the associated residual network $N\left(V=A\cup B,\,F=\lbrace(a_i,b_j)\,|\,e_{ij}\notin M_0\rbrace\cup\lbrace(b_j,a_i)\,|\,e_{ij}\in M_0\rbrace\right)$ and weights $\omega(a_i,b_j)=w(e_{ij}),\,\omega(b_j,a_i)=-w(e_{ij})$.

If however a negative cycles exists in $N$ then $M_1\ :=\ (M_0\setminus\nu)\cup \pi$, where $\nu$ and $\pi$ denote the edges of $G$ that correspond  to negative, resp. positive arcs of negative cycles in $N$, has lower weight.

The apparently unconditionally recommended method for finding a the arcs of a negative cycle in $N$ is the Bellman-Ford shortest path algorithm with $O(mn)$ runtime complexity.

However it seems to me that something taylored for the special properties of the residual network $N$ could bring about a performance boost.
The underlying idea is simple enough:
Construct from the edges in $M_0$ an alternative network $\mathcal{N}$, that contains arc set $\lbrace (b_j, a_i)\,|\,e_{ij}\in M_0\rbrace\cup\lbrace(a_i,b_{j_0})\,|\,e_{ij}\notin M_0\,\land\,\omega(a_i,b_{j_0})\le\omega(a_i,b_j)\rbrace$ where the weights of arcs are as defined for $N$. Put differently, connect the end of negative arcs with the nearest start of a different negative arc.
As the outdegree of every arc in $\mathcal{N}$ is exactly $1$, the underlying undirected graph has the topology of a $1$-forest, a graph, in which *every* connected component has *exactly* one cycle.
Repeatedly deleting from $\mathcal{N}$ all arcs with indegree 0 (the sources) leaves a collection of directed cycles in which the negatives ones can be trivially identified as the (strongly) connected components with negative arc-weight sum.

The complexity of the suggested alternative method can be easily determined as $O(m-n/2)$ for finding the shortest positive outgoing arc of a negative one plus $O(n)$ for repeatedly removing the source nodes in $\mathcal{N}$ when executed sequentially.

> **Question:**
>
> when will the proposed alternative way of detecting negative cycles in the residual network of minimum weight perfect bipartite matching fail, resp. will it always detect one if it exists?
>
> Could it ever report false positives, i.e. yield a negative cycle if there actually isn't one? If not, the proposed method could be used to do the "bulk work" before resorting to Bellman-Ford.

**Addendum:**

In view of [John Machacek](https://mathoverflow.net/users/51668/john-machacek)'s answer I see the need for clarification and making things explicit.

- the task is to determine the perfect matching of minimum weight in a *symmetric* bipartite graph, however as $e_{ij}:=\lbrace a_i\in A,\,b_j\in B\rbrace$ is a shorthand notation for $e_{a_i b_j}=e_{b_j a_i}$, the order of indices is significant and $e_{ii}$ doesn't denote a self loop in $G$.
  Consequently $w(e_{ij})$ can be different from $w(e_{ji})$
- the end node $a_i$ and start node $b_{j_0}$ of negative arcs that are connected by the positive arc $\lbrace a_i, b_{j_0}\rbrace$ must not belong to the same negative arc, i.e. $\mathcal{N}$ must not contain pairs of antiparallel arcs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand notation correctly $e_{ij}$ is the edge $\{a_i, b_j\}$ in $G$. I'll let $w_{ij}$ be the weight $e_{ij}$. I'll give an example showing the alternative method can fail to detect a negative cycle in $N$. Consider

$$w_{11} = \epsilon$$
$$w_{12} = B$$
$$w_{13} = B$$
$$w_{21} = B$$
$$w_{22} = A$$
$$w_{23}= B - \epsilon$$
$$w_{31} = B + 3\epsilon$$
$$w_{32} = B + 2\epsilon$$
$$w_{33} = \epsilon$$
Where $\epsilon > 0$ is small while $A$ and $B$ are large with  $B < A < 2B - \epsilon$. Let $M_0 = \{e_{12}, e_{21}, e_{33}\}$. Then $N$ contains the negative cycle
$$(a_1, b_1), (b_1, a_2), (a_2, b_2), (b_2,a_1)$$
which has weight $\epsilon - B + A -B = A + \epsilon - 2B < 0$. Indeed, $M_0$ is not minimal weight. The minimal weight matching is $M^* = \{e_{11}, e_{22}, e_{33}\}$.

In this example $\mathcal{N}$ consists of arcs
$$\{(b_2, a_1), (b_1, a_2), (b_3, a_3), (a_1, b_1), (a_2, b_3), (a_3, b_2)\}$$
or
$$\{(b_2, a_1), (b_1, a_2), (b_3, a_3), (a_1, b_1), (a_2, b_3), (a_3, b_3)\}$$
(it depends on my understanding of the definition of $\mathcal{N}$ and if $e_{i,j_0}$ is allowed to be in $M_0$ or not).

Either way we fail to find a negative cycle. In the latter case the only cycle is $(a_3, b_3), (b_3, a_3)$ which has weight $0$. In the first case we have a cycle will all the arcs
$$(a_1,b_1), (b_1,a_2), (a_2, b_3), (b_3, a_3), (a_3,b_2), (b_2, a_1)$$
which has weight $\epsilon - B + (B - \epsilon) - \epsilon + (B + 2\epsilon) - B = \epsilon > 0$.